# Using holomorphic functions to approximate some meromorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\left\{z:\dfrac {3}{4}<\left|z\right|<1\right\}$ ，$f_{1}\left(z\right)=\dfrac{1}{2z-1}$ and $f_{2}\left(z\right)=\dfrac{1}{2z-3}$.

Is it possible to uniformly approximate $f_{1}$ or $f_{2}$ on $A$ by functions analytic on $D$.

My thought: From Runge's theorem,there exists a sequence of meromorphic functions with poles on the components of $C^{\ast}/A$ converges uniformly on $A$. Since the disk centered at zero with radius $\dfrac{3}{4}$ is also one of its components,the functions in the sequence can't all be analytic on unit disk.

Is my thought valid? Are there some more direct or down to earth argument to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know about Laurent series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D=\{|z|<1\}$, I presume.
$f_2$ is already holomorphic on $D$. But the answer is no for $f_1$. You may also give lower bounds for the distance:

Suppose $h(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$ is holomorphic on $D$ and $|f_1(z)-h(z)|<\epsilon$ on $A$. Write $f_1(z)=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-1/2z}=\sum_{k\leq -1} 2^k z^k$ (Laurent series on $A$). Then difference has the following Laurent series:

$$\Delta(z)\equiv h(z)-f_1(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_k z^k - \sum_{k\leq -1} 2^k z^k \equiv \sum_{n\in {\mathbb Z}} c_n z^n.$$

By Cauchy, we have:
$$ c_n = \oint_{C} \Delta(z) z^{-n-1} \frac{dz}{2\pi i}$$

Take a contour aribitrarily close to the unit circle to get for $n\leq -1$:
$$ 2^n = |c_n| \leq  \oint_C |\Delta(z)|\frac{|dz|}{2\pi} \leq \epsilon.$$
For $n=-1$ this implies a distance (for the uniform norm) of at least $\epsilon \geq 1/2$. You may generalize this to any $f$ holomorphic on $A$. If arbitrarily well approximated by functions holomorphic in $D$ then $f$ itself extends to a holomorphic function in $D$.